# Blender FBX Export Error: location <unknown location>:-1

Tags: error, .fbx

When I try to export an object using .fbx, I get unknown location error every single time. I do select the folder, but even after that, I get this error.

[image]

I use Blender v.2.83.4

[image]

I have tried to redownload Blender and I still receive the same error.

Comment: The error itself is just a line above <unknown location> part, where it says "utf-8 codec can't decode byte 0xc4...". Do you by any chance store file in OneDrive or similar? See https://developer.blender.org/T74510.

Comment: No, I do not store the file in OneDrive or similar.

Comment: Hello! Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Edit the question with more information about what you've done to troubleshoot, e.g whether you use internet connection for anything related to Blender, do you get error if exporting a certain object or all of them, do you have any non-English letters in objects' names to export etc. I have seen that error only related to what was mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

I had this error on and off for a while.

I think it has to do with leaving objects in edit mode. Especially if you have more than one object still in edit mode. If you make all the objects in the scene visible and make sure none of them are in edit mode, it seems to fix it.

You may have to save out to a different file name as well.